# Get a variable out of a 'Model' -- Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates, custom-tags

I have a complicated question, so I hope I can write it in a understandable way. I have a template (index.html) and I'm using a custom tag for setting a few variable.

I can set this varible with:

```
{% set table_breaker_houses = 4 %}
```

And I use it later many times with, for example:

```
{% if forloop.counter <= table_breaker_houses %}
```

This is how it works now, but I want something like this:

```
{% for settings in Settings %}
{% set table_breaker_houses = "{{ settings.table_breaker_houses }}" %}
{% endfor %}

{% if forloop.counter <= table_breaker_houses %}
```

"Settings" is a model with values, so I can manage my settings with the adminpanel.

Could someone please help me out?
Thanks for readings so far and sorry for my bad english. :)

With best regards,
borsTiHD

Comment: It's not clear wha you are trying to do. Why do you repeatedly set the same variable inside the loop? What are you expecting the value to be at the end of the loop?

Comment: I use the variable "table_breaker_houses" to end a html table and start a new table. With the help of forloop.counter and my variable I can end/start the table after a specific number of entrys. :) And " {% if forloop.counter <= settings.table_breaker_houses %} " is not working. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the quotes and `{{}}`.

Use the variables directly within the tag:

```
{% for settings in Settings %}
   {% set table_breaker_houses = settings.table_breaker_houses %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, be sure `Settings` is a queryset or an iterable, and not just a model.

Comment: Sounds good, but I dont bring it to work. What exactly do you mean by "Also, be sure Settings is a queryset or an iterable, and not just a model."? Because I think this is my problem here. :D

Comment: Eh, you should pass settings as an iterable from your views. It is not related to the original problem tho.

Comment: Hm, ok... I must read more and I will try it. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have my problem solved.

```
{% set table_breaker_houses = settings.table_breaker_houses %}
```

This is working, but only in the same "for" loop. Outside my loop my variable is empty. I hope this helps others too. :)